# Cómo arreglar esta vulnerabilidad de tipo Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, seguridad

En mi proyecto usamos snyk como escáner para detectar vulnerabilidades, tengo que arreglar una pero hasta ahora no encuentro una solución, espero me puedan ayudar, el fragmento del código es el siguiente:

```
  public async Task<string> GetHtml(string urlContent)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            try
            {
                urlContent = Uri.EscapeUriString(urlContent);
                using (httpClient)
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderAccept, HeaderAcceptValue);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderAcceptEncoding, HeaderAcceptEncodingValue);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderUserAgent, HeaderUserAgentValue);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderAcceptCharset, HeaderAcceptCharsetValue);
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(TextHelper.RedirectUrlNull(urlContent)));
```

Se supone que el problema es referente a la variable de urlContent y cómo se relaciona con var response, pero no logro saber bien cómo mitigar esa vulnerabilidad.
Les agradezco de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que hacer una lista blanca de URL admitidas